# Term for the contraction of all the edges of a (connected) induced subgraph?

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a graph that contains at least one connected subset of vertices.

Let S be a connected subset of vertices of G.

Let G[S] denote the induced subgraph of S in G.

Let's consider an operation that transforms G to another graph G' by contracting all the edges of G[S].

Informally speaking, it consists of "condensing" or "contracting" G[S] to one vertex (always possible as S is connected), while conserving all the edges that connect a vertex in S to a vertex outside of S.

Is there a particular name used to call such a type of operation? May one say this is the contraction of S in G, or is there any other more appropriate term, if any?

Supplementary question: Is there a particular name used to call the relationship between G and G'?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Let me know if there's an itch my answer doesn't scratch.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a quotient map in other contexts, and I would write it as $G/S$ to indicate that I've used an equivalence relation to identify all vertices in $S$, or $G/{\sim}$ if instead I specify an equivalence relation denoted ${\sim}$.

It seems graph theory has this same notion (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_graph)). Given the context in which quotient maps arise in mathematics, namely topology, it makes sense that graph theorists would use the same notation; graphs are a commonly studied topology.

In particular, it seems a condensation is a specific type of quotient graph related to what you're curious to know more about. A condensation is when each strongly connected component is treated as a single vertex.

As for what to call $G/S$? In topology, you might see it called the quotient space; in graph theory, it seems it is called the quotient graph.

PS there is a related notion in topology called a deformation retract, which you can read about [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retraction_(topology)). Unfortunately, that Wiki article is pretty bad in my opinion. Instead, I like Hatcher's treatment. You can find a PDF of his book [here](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/ATpage.html). The section on deformation retracts is short. A more basic topology book, like [Monkres](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/product/Munkres-Topology-2nd-Edition/9780131816299.html), would provide a good discussion of quotient maps and quotient spaces, but maybe this is more detailed than what you wanted to know.